# inner join on cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp, join

well I need to do a inner join fron 2 tables, but always obtain the same error, I send this from postman, I am trying to recieve the id a execute the inner join with this two tables, now use this example from [documentation](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#adding-joins)

```
{
  "message": "Failed calling Cake\\ORM\\Query::jsonSerialize()",
  "url": "/users/userdata",
  "code": 500
}
```

And error log:

```
2017-04-20 01:50:24 Error: [Exception] Failed calling Cake\ORM\Query::jsonSerialize()
Request URL: /users/userdata
Stack Trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\dekma_backend\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\View\JsonView.php(0): json_encode()
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\dekma_backend\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\View\SerializedView.php(98): Cake\View\JsonView->_serialize(Array)
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\dekma_backend\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\View\JsonView.php(107): Cake\View\SerializedView->render(NULL, NULL)
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\dekma_backend\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Controller\Controller.php(623): Cake\View\JsonView->render(NULL, NULL)
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\dekma_backend\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Http\ActionDispatcher.php(125): Cake\Controller\Controller->render()
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\dekma_backend\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Http\ActionDispatcher.php(93): Cake\Http\ActionDispatcher->_invoke(Object(App\Controller\UsersController))
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\dekma_backend\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Http\BaseApplication.php(78): Cake\Http\ActionDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Response))
#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\dekma_backend\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Http\Runner.php(65): Cake\Http\BaseApplication->__invoke(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Response), Object(Cake\Http\Runner))
#8 C:\xampp\htdocs\dekma_backend\vendor\ozee31\cakephp-cors\src\Routing\Middleware\CorsMiddleware.php(28): Cake\Http\Runner->__invoke(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Response))
#9 C:\xampp\htdocs\dekma_backend\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Http\Runner.php(65): Cors\Routing\Middleware\CorsMiddleware->__invoke(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Response), Object(Cake\Http\Runner))
#10 C:\xampp\htdocs\dekma_backend\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Routing\Middleware\RoutingMiddleware.php(59): Cake\Http\Runner->__invoke(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Response))
#11 C:\xampp\htdocs\dekma_backend\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Http\Runner.php(65): Cake\Routing\Middleware\RoutingMiddleware->__invoke(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Response), Object(Cake\Http\Runner))
#12 C:\xampp\htdocs\dekma_backend\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Routing\Middleware\AssetMiddleware.php(88): Cake\Http\Runner->__invoke(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Response))
#13 C:\xampp\htdocs\dekma_backend\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Http\Runner.php(65): Cake\Routing\Middleware\AssetMiddleware->__invoke(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Response), Object(Cake\Http\Runner))
#14 C:\xampp\htdocs\dekma_backend\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Error\Middleware\ErrorHandlerMiddleware.php(92): Cake\Http\Runner->__invoke(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Response))
#15 C:\xampp\htdocs\dekma_backend\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Http\Runner.php(65): Cake\Error\Middleware\ErrorHandlerMiddleware->__invoke(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Response), Object(Cake\Http\Runner))
#16 C:\xampp\htdocs\dekma_backend\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Http\Runner.php(51): Cake\Http\Runner->__invoke(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Response))
#17 C:\xampp\htdocs\dekma_backend\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Http\Server.php(80): Cake\Http\Runner->run(Object(Cake\Http\MiddlewareQueue), Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Response))
#18 C:\xampp\htdocs\dekma_backend\webroot\index.php(38): Cake\Http\Server->run()
#19 {main}
```

the controller:

```
  public function userdata()
    {

        $query = $this->Users->find('all')
            ->join([
                'subsection' => [
                    'table' => 'subsections',
                    'type' => 'inner',
                    'conditions' => 'users.subsection_id = subsections.id',
                ],
                'city' => [
                    'table' => 'cities',
                    'type' => 'INNER',
                    'conditions' => 'users.city_id = cities.id',
                ]
            ]);

        //$user = $this->Users->get($id);

        $this->set([
            'success' => true,
            'data' => $query,
            '_serialize' => ['success', 'data']
        ]);
    }
```

Mysql that I need is this:

```
SELECT * FROM mydb.users
INNER JOIN subsections on users.subsection_id = subsections.id
INNER JOIN cities on users.city_id = cities.id;
```

I change version php nos work but the select is not working for table subsections and cities

[image]

Comment: are you able to inspect your final sql command? also have you included the specified namespace/path inside your controller?

Comment: I can't inspect sql command when I send json data from postman is this a problem.

Comment: no i just wanted you to inspect that query inside your sql console, to look if it has errors or no?

Comment: yes work i probe this sql on my workbench

Comment: Check whether the query can be executed without problems in the first place, ie make sure that it doesn't throw an exception. Also what's your PHP version? Before PHP 5.6.27, the actual exception will be wrapped in a "Failed calling jsonSerialize()" exception.

Comment: Yes,  the query can be executed without problems. Possibly that's the reason I have PHP 5.6.24

Comment: Just to make that clear, when I say query, then I'm referring to the CakePHP query builder, ie `$query->all()`, I'm not referring to the SQL that you're showing in your question!

Comment: Yes is correct, dont have error, I update the question you can see.

Answer (score 1):

Please add `->toArray();` after query like this:

```
$query = $this->Users->find('all')
            ->join([
                'subsection' => [
                    'table' => 'subsections',
                    'type' => 'inner',
                    'conditions' => 'users.subsection_id = subsections.id',
                ],
                'city' => [
                    'table' => 'cities',
                    'type' => 'INNER',
                    'conditions' => 'users.city_id = cities.id',
                ]
            ])->toArray();
```

And check it. I hope it will help you.